# Phrase or idiom for lots of unnecessary actions

Tags: phrase-requests, slang, idiom-requests

I am looking for a short phrase or idiom which means "a lot of unnecessary and hard actions".

The whole phrase would be something like:
No more *tons of unnecessary actions*, create it in one minute or less.
It means that here is a new simple and quick way to create something, and you could avoid a lot of work you were usually doing in old software to gain same result.

I was thinking about "hustle and bustle" but I don't know is it suitable for case where you are interacting with software.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hustle and bustle is usually associated with the random busyness of crowds. *No more fuss / messing around / busywork.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t want to have to **jump through a lot of hoops**:

> to have to do a lot of things that seem difficult or unnecessary in order to achieve something — [Colins](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/jump-through-hoops)

This idiom is appropriate in a wide variety of situations but here’s an example with computers:

> [Computers have learned to make us jump through hoops](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/commentisfree/2018/nov/18/computers-have-learned-to-make-us-jump-through-hoops)
>
> Machines are supposed to be tools that serve human ends, but the relationship is slowly shifting - and not in our favour

Comment: Thank you. This is describing hard and unnecessary as i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For a phrase more appropriate to software, I suggest [**bells and whistles**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bells%20and%20whistles):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : items or features that are useful or decorative but not essential : FRILLS
>
> // Sure, any car purchased in the future will have a battery of electronic assistants, but keeping the *bells and whistles* to a minimum and making them engage with the car will only improve confidence.
> — Ezra Dyer, *Car and Driver*, "The Debate: Should Your Teen Drive a New Car or an Old Beater?," 23 Apr. 2020

A sentence in the context of software could be something like this:

> Don't spend so much time on all the *bells and whistles*. All we need is a basic interface with a Yes button and a No button.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it is almost what i was looking for. It lacks action meaning, but i will figure out how to formulate action in addition to this one.

Answer (score 0):

How about the idiom **red tape**? From Lexico:

> **[red tape](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/red_tape)**: Excessive bureaucracy or adherence to rules and formalities, especially in public business.

**Red tape** entails "a lot of unnecessary and hard actions". With **red tape**, your "whole phrase" would read:

> No more **red tape**, create it in one minute or less. It means that here is a new simple and quick way to create something, and you could avoid a lot of work you were usually doing … to gain same result.

Comment: Thank you. Will ordinary people understand this idiom? I mean, how common this idiom is?

Comment: @Userich This is a very commonly used idiom when it comes to procedures and processes that involve a lot paperwork, e.g., forms.